# How to specify multiple labels for a given data point in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to solve a classification problem using a sequential keras model.

In Keras, `model.fit` requires two `numpy` arrays to train on - `data`, `labels`.
This works correctly if each row of the data has one corresponding label.

However, for my use, I have more than one classification possible for a given data point.

Can this be handled in keras? If so, what should be the format of my data and labels numpy array?

Sample inputs could look like this:

```
data[0] = ['What is the colour of the shirt?'] 
#This text is converted to a vector using a 300 dimension GloVe embedding layer and then processed. 

label[0] = ['Red','Orange','Brown']
```

I require my model to train such that any of the 3 classes can be correct for the given question asked.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you explain more? Give more examples of questions and what kinds of answers you're expecting. ---- Also: when you listed ['Red', 'Orange', 'Brown'], do you mean that the shirt has all three colors?

Comment: I mean that the any of the answers ['Red','Orange','Brown'] are correct. I am building a visual question answer system where for a given image and a given question, there may be multiple correct answers. So, I'd like my classifier to train such that when a similar question is asked on a similar image, any of the these colours should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with MultiLabelBinarizer:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

lb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
label = lb.fit_transform(label)
```

you can than pass the labels to the fit function with 'categorical_crossentropy' loss.

if you want to do it with keras:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

unique_labels, new_labels = np.unique(label, return_inverse=True)
to_categorical(new_labels, num_classes=None)
```

Comment: I would only want a keras solution. Scikit Learn solution wouldn't work